# Using GoogleMaps app installed on the phone already

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent

Please be patient if my question is a little stupid, but. I'm designing an application which will use GoogleMaps. But what happens if user doesn't have a GoogleMaps on his phone? I'll try to open it, but it will be kinda NullPointer or what? Is there anybody experienced who can explain in few words how do I need to check if Maps are installed and if not to tell user that my app requires Maps installed?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no google maps installed in his phone 2 things will occur.

1) The phone will ask the user to install the google maps

**or**

2)The phone will tell to download google play services.

By default all android phones have google maps installed in them, the only phones which do not have maps are emulators.
But then you can downoad the google play services for them.